# No Git deployment for Ghost blog deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, git, ghost-blog

I have deployed Ghost to an Azure (Shared) web app using the One-Click option [here](https://github.com/AzureWebApps/Ghost-Azure). I am trying to get at the source code but there is no option for Git deployment in the Azure portal:

[image]

I have tried add an FTP/deployment user name in the deployment credentials but there is still no option for Git in the portal?

**More info:**

1. There is no option when I click **continuous deployment** to configure GitHub:

[image: continuous deployment screen]

2. I have already filled out **deployment credentials** but am only given ftp options:

[image: deployment credentials]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your web app, and select all settings, the properties will be the screen you have posted, lower down there should be 'Continuous Deployment' and 'Deployment Credentials' where you can configure Github etc.

[image]

Comment: I have added more info - there doesn't seem to be any way to configure GitHub? I wonder if this is to do with the fact it was deployed with the 'One-Click' deployment option as I mentioned in my original post?

Comment: @NRKirby If you click on the disconnect button in Continuous deployment, you can reconfigure it all from there

Comment: @Micheal B Thanks, I've done that. How do I then get the source code from Azure to a GitHub repository?

Comment: That's probably the basis for a new question! - but [this](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/) might help and maybe [this](https://desktop.github.com/)